# Custom ListView setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to implement Custom ListView into my android app. But it doesn't works. I've tried to solve this by adding the following lines, but it didn't work for me.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

The codes are given below-

**my_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#00aee5">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/laptop"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Laptop"
        android:background="#53e1e9"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.android.imran.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

        final String[] my_laptops={"Asus","Acer","Lenovo","HP","DELL","Surface","MacBook"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> my_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.my_list, R.id.mytxt,my_laptops);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "U clicked on "+my_laptops[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        list.setAdapter(my_adapter);
    }
}
```

What is causing the problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="#00aee5"
              android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is another problem. This doesn't work when I click on the image button given into the list item. But it works when I click on the other area of the list item. How can it be fixed?

Comment: @AbdullahAlImran Why do you use ImageButton if you don't want to click on it? Use ImageView instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Image-Buttons in list item, try this:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in the **mylist** or row activity's main layout.

Now for Image-Button(s) in the **mylist**, try this:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Let me know, if it works for you.!

Comment: I've added `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the **LinearLayout** of **activity_main.xml** and added `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in the **ImageButton** of **mylist.xml**.
But it didn't worked for me. :(

Comment: It works when I added `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the **LinearLayout** of **mylist.xml**. Thank you. :)